# 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_get_distribution_strategy'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, callback, conv-neural-network

I have a problem since yesterday and I don't understand why. I read lot's of similar subjects here but I didn't found any solution in my case.

My imports are the following :

```
import numpy as np
import librosa.display
import utils
import librosa
import os
import keras

from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
```

My model is :

```
    model = keras.Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(2, 2), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    model.add(Conv2D(48, kernel_size=(2, 2), activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    model.add(Conv2D(120, kernel_size=(2, 2), activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(Flatten())

    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
                  optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

And finally :

```
keras_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./Graph',
                                             histogram_freq=1,
                                             write_graph=True,
                                             write_images=True)

cnn_model.fit(X_train,
              y_train,
              batch_size=64,
              epochs=1,
              verbose=1,
              validation_split=0.1,
              callbacks=[keras_callback])
```

My error :

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-e1e874d24f0c> in <module>
     11               verbose=1,
     12               validation_split=0.1,
---> 13               callbacks=[keras_callback])

c:\users\antoine\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
   1237                                         steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
   1238                                         validation_steps=validation_steps,
-> 1239                                         validation_freq=validation_freq)
   1240 
   1241     def evaluate(self,

c:\users\antoine\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py in fit_loop(model, fit_function, fit_inputs, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_function, val_inputs, shuffle, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq)
    117         callback_metrics += ['val_' + n for n in model.metrics_names]
    118 
--> 119     callbacks.set_model(callback_model)
    120     callbacks.set_params({
    121         'batch_size': batch_size,

c:\users\antoine\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks\callbacks.py in set_model(self, model)
     66         self.model = model
     67         for callback in self.callbacks:
---> 68             callback.set_model(model)
     69 
     70     def _call_batch_hook(self, mode, hook, batch, logs=None):

c:\users\antoine\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks\tensorboard_v2.py in set_model(self, model)
    114         """Sets Keras model and writes graph if specified."""
    115         model.run_eagerly = False
--> 116         super(TensorBoard, self).set_model(model)

c:\users\antoine\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py in set_model(self, model)
   1530     # possibly distributed settings.
   1531     self._log_write_dir = distributed_file_utils.write_dirpath(
-> 1532         self.log_dir, self.model._get_distribution_strategy())  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   1533 
   1534     with context.eager_mode():

AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_get_distribution_strategy'
```

I am using Tensorboard 2.1.0, tensorflow 2.1.0, Keras 2.3.1.

Thank you, you can ask me if you want more details !

Comment: Your not using `tensorflow.keras`. I think pure Keras doesn't have these distribution strategies (I may be wrong, though)

Comment: I tried both and no one works actually

Answer (score 0):

Can you please prefix 'tf' wherever you are using keras and also import tensor flow

1. Add to the code

   import tensorflow as tf
2. Prefix with 'tf' wherever keras is found. For eaxmple:

From

```
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization
from keras.utils import to_categorical
```

To

```
from tf.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from tf.keras.models import Sequential
from tf.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization
from tf.keras.utils import to_categorical
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for you help. When I apply the changes, I have a new error :

('Could not interpret optimizer identifier:', <keras.optimizers.Adadelta object at 0x000002A2D7DFB7C8>)

on the line
 cnn_model = get_cnn_model(input_shape, classes)

With the model in my post, and even when I try to change tensorflow.keras.Sequential() or keras.sequential() that does not work.

Comment: @Aear: Did you updated model.compile code as below 

```model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
                  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])```



Please can you clarify

Comment: Thank you very much. I added a parameter "profile_batch" in keras_callback for make it works and make the change you told. But with using tensorflow.keras.blabla instead of keras.blabla makes my model very slow to train, before I needed like 50 epochs to reach 98% accuracy and 0.2 lost and now with 400 epochs I got 45% acc and 1.6 loss, is that normal ??

Comment: @Aear, if i have answer your question please accept answer and up vote it. Thank you.